# here file does not fill token

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, automation

I use a certain command quite frequently, but the command prompts a few things so I wanted to auto-fill it with here file, but it seems that for some reason it can't provide last value to the prompt. Do you have any idea why?

The command is `databricks configure --token` from databricks cli package.
it first prompts for host's URL and then for a token to be used.

My script with here file looks like this:

```
if [ ! -v DATABRICKS_HOST ]; then
    echo "DATARBICKS_HOST vairiable is not set."
    exit 15

elif [ -z "$DATABRICKS_HOST" ]; then
    echo "DATARBICKS_HOST is set but is empty."
    exit 16

fi

if [ ! -v DATABRICKS_TOKEN ]; then
    echo "DATARBICKS_HOST vairiable is not set."
    exit 17

elif [ -z "$DATABRICKS_TOKEN" ]; then
    echo "DATARBICKS_HOST is set but is empty."
    exit 18

fi

databricks configure --token << EOF
$DATABRICKS_HOST
$DATABRICKS_TOKEN
EOF
```

This script is called from another file that first sets up some env variables, among them DATABRICKS_HOST and DATABRICKS_TOKEN. I checked and variables are available in ENVironment when I echo them.

This is what I get after calling the script.

[image: This is what I get after calling the script.]

The token is not provided although here file should do it. I have to open the file and copy the token in, so copying the values to the token prompt is possible.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: It may be simpler to export the variables, rather than trying to use the interactive CLI non-interactively - see for example [How do I use databricks-cli without manual configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51837063/how-do-i-use-databricks-cli-without-manual-configuration)